# Broken filter. Code should only move accounts with email address that have 2 uppercase letters

Tags: python, filter

The code below should only move accounts with email address that have 2 uppercase letters at the end 2 places behind the "@" sign. The filter appears to catch everything instead.

I have changed how far the value goes back in the username and check_email variables.

```
mike@gmail.com
toTR@yahoo.com
erferTT@hotmail.com 
fwefEE@yahoo.com
thisYY@aol.com
that@yahoo.com
```

The first and last email addresses should be omitted and the remaining should be placed into a new file, but the lowercase email addresses are being pulled as well.

Thanks

```
import sys
import argparse
from datetime import datetime

def parse_arg():

    """Parses the args"""    
    if len(sys.argv) < 1:
        print("Args: Input filename")
        raise RuntimeError("Insufficient arguments.")

    arg_1 = sys.argv[1]

    return arg_1

#Parameter is the filename
filename = parse_arg()

#Create filename for output
output_file_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%I%M%S")
output_file = output_file_date + '_' + filename

#Access the input file
with open(filename, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_file, 'w') as file_output:

    #Create the header"""
    output_file_header = input_file.readline().decode().replace('\r','')
    file_output.write(output_file_header)

    #Skip the header in the input file
    next(input_file)

       #iterate over file object line by line
        for line in input_file:

        #Create output file objects
        lines = line.decode().split(',')

        #Create the email username variable
        username = lines[1].split('@')[0]

        #Create variable that display last two characters
        check_email = username[-1:]

  #Create file based on business rules and write results to file.
        if check_email.isupper(): #and len(username) < 16:
            output_data = ','.join(lines).replace('\r','')
            file_output.write(output_data)
```

Comment: `check_email = username[-1:]` only gets the last (single) letter..so if the 2nd to last letter is lowercase, it will still think its valid. Would `check_email = username[-2:]` fix this?

Comment: Its always something small. Now it works as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking here the last character, and not the last 2 characters.

Instead of writing 
`check_email = username[-1:]`
just do
`check_email = username[-2:]`

The number defined there is how many letters its gonna take.

Also as always i would recommend you to print out what you actually get from each line, so you get a better understanding and see a bit better what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'll be using the println more often.